# Any chrome pages do not load in chrome but normal sites work fine

Tags: google-chrome

Ok so, I have one computer where any "chrome://" pages do not load and instead have the "aw snap..." error. This includes extensions, settings, about or even trying to login to chrome with a google account. However, I can navigate to any non-chrome page by using the address bar at the top so normal websites work fine.

This is what I have tried so far

Uninstalled and reinstalled chrome,
Uninstalled and reinstalled chrome with the offline installer,
Cleared out google appdata, program files (and x86) and programdata
Revo uninstaller on Chrome,
Ran sfc scan,
Ran chkdsk,
Tried different user account.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up just wiping the system and starting over, only took a few hours so much easier than trying to find a solution to a problem that apparently nobody else has seen.

Answer (score 0):

Try: chrome://apps/ . This link works fine for me.

Comment: What should OP do on that page?

Comment: No chrome:// links work as I already stated in the original post.